# How can i write an if statement for a button to be visible?

Tags: selenium

I have a button on a page that is not displayed sometimes. I would like for my code to go around it, but it won't work with`driver.findElement.isDisplayed()` . I was thinking of `ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable`, but i don't know how to make it boolean. Some help please?(of course, the condition is returning error as it's not boolean).

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        if(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("html//body//div[5]//div//div//form//div//div[1]//div[3]//div//div//div//input")).){
            WebElement ex = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid'][@value='export'][@type='radio']"));
            ex.click();
            WebElement in = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html//body//div[5]//div//div//form//div//div[1]//div[3]//div//div//div//input"));
            in.click();
        }else{new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("html//body//div[5]//div//div//form//div//div[1]//div[3]//div//div//div//input")));}
```

'

Comment: You can always transform statement that throws an exception instead of returning false to boolean statement with try/catch block.

Answer (score 1):

`findElement` returns either element or throws `NoSuchElementException`, So to determine element is visible with if condition You should try using `findElements` instead because it's returns either list of WebElement or empty list, so you just check its `size` as below :-

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("your xpath"));

//Now check it size
if(elements.size() > 0 && elements.get(0).isDisplayed())
{
   WebElement element = elements.get(0);
  //Now do your further stuff with this element 
}
```

Comment: You are not waiting for elements to appear